# How do I prevent the body mesh from protruding through the clothes mesh?

Tags: mesh, makehuman

[image]

I have tried deleting vertices, but that doesn't work. Is there another way to hide this problem?

Comment: Couldn't you just pull the clothes away from the body in the parts where they're overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any geometry under your model's clothing at all, the simplest thing to do is to export it using the option to *hide faces under clothes* in MakeHuman. [image]

This way, all faces under clothes will be hidden for you.

Comment: ok cool. thanks, but how would i be able to return the skin in blender or would i have import and export again to see the skin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the model underneath, use the Mask Modifier to hide the unwanted geometry.

Create a Vertex Group and Assign with a strength of 1.0 on the parts of the mesh you want hidden, name it whatever you want. Add the Mask Modifier and choose the Vertex Group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Blender, another option would be:

1) Select the clothes; 
2) Go into Sculpt mode; 
3) Choose the Inflate tool from the tools on the left, and then blow up the clothes a little bit, so it covers the body; 
4) Repeat step 3 for all the exposing areas.

Comment: I would sure hope you and the OP are using blender. If not then they asked on the wrong site.

Comment: @David yes good point...